# Ocultar Peticion API REST AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

estoy realizando un chat de mensageria instantanes pero quiero que no se muestre las a peticociones al servidor, como el Messenger de Facebook o gmail que no sale ninguna peticion pero estan sincronizados; lo hice en AJAX

```html
function pullData(){
    $("#comment").load(" #comment");
    $("#notification").load(" #notification");
    
    if(userto!=''&&userto!=undefined){
        retrieveChatMessages();
        retrieveTypingStatus();
    }
    setTimeout(pullData,3000);
}

function retrieveChatMessages(){
    $.post($("#uri").val()+'/retrieveChatMessages', {userto: userto}, function(data){
        if (data.length > 0)
            $('#chat-window').append(data);
            $('#chat-window').scrollTop($('#chat-window')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
}

function retrieveTypingStatus(){
    $.post($("#uri").val()+'/retrieveTypingStatus', {userto: userto}, function(userto){
        if (userto.length > 0)
            $('#typingStatus').html(userto+' is typing');
        else
            $('#typingStatus').html('');
    });
}
```

la cual se actualiza cada 3 segundos y funciona, solo que sale a quien se le escribe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o alguna otra forma de hacerlo, con ReactJS ocurre lo mismo

Comment: eso es porque esos chat no utilizan peticiones `http`  si no que utilizan `websockets`

Answer (score 0):

Es imposible ocultar las peticiones ajax, ya que al final y al cabo, son peticiones HTTP común y corrientes como al entrar a leer el diario online.

La forma en que se realiza un chat de manera es por medio de *sockets*, mejor dicho, *Web Sockets* cuando se habla en un intercambio que pasa por la web. Por medio de sockets podrás comunicarte de manera mucho mas rápida, segura (podrás aplicarle algoritmos de cifrado/encriptación/etc), podrás hacer chats P2P mucho mas eficientes, etc.... todo depende a que tipo de chat estés tratando de hacer (tipo los viejos Terra o un whatsapp), transferís datos en binario no en texto puro como lo hace ajax.

Puedes utilizar la librería Socket.io que es una tool que comunica JS como cliente y NodeJS como server/host por medio de websockets (tb puede utilizarse otros lenguajes). Otro ejemplo es la librería SignalR de .Net.

Es de descontar que por ejemplo Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp, Telegram utilizan sockets y el paquete de información que envía es en formato binario propietario para cada caso (lo que se llama empaquetación del mensaje, que es un protocolo predefinido de comunicación entre un cliente y un servidor).

Por otro lado, la ventaja de usar Sockets, es que no tendrás que estar continuamente haciendo ping al server para saber si un usuario esta escribiendo (esto es una terrible idea y en poco tiempo se te cae el server si hay muchos usuarios)... sino que un socket escucha de manera activa un ip/puerto y ni bien comienzan a llegar datos, ya puedes mostrar "el usuario x esta escribiendo". O sea... ni bien alguien comienza a escribir, se realiza un broadcast a todos los otros clientes conectados en la sala, cada cliente "escucha" eventos que provienen y puede reaccionar en consecuencia.

Te dejo un ejemplo de chat con socket.io de su documentación oficial https://socket.io/get-started/chat.

Obviamente, puedes consultarme lo que necesites para seguir profundizando en el tema....